# Python program to remove C type single and multiple line comments

Tags: python

Here is the code I've tried,

```
from re import *


commentStart = compile('/\*')
commentEnd = compile('\*/')
singleComment = compile('//')
quotes = compile('".*"')

def readComment(line):

    while(line):
        if(commentEnd.match(line)):
            return
        line = input()

line=input()

while(line):
    if(quotes.match(line)):
        print(line)
        line = input()
        continue

    elif(commentStart.match(line)):

        readComment(line)
        line=input()
        continue

    elif(singleComment.match(line)):
        line=input()
        continue

    else:
        print(line)

    line=input()
```

I'm able to remove the single line comments but i have problem with the multi line comments.

Sample input:

```
abcd
//blah
efg
/*blah
blah
blah*/
hij
```

My Output:

```
abcd
efg
```

Expected Output:

```
abcd
efg
hij
```

Please point out where I've made mistake. Thankyou.

Comment: On SO, if you've received an answer you can use you should mark it accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one:

```
commentEnd.match(line)
```

Should be:

```
commentEnd.search(line)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match):

> If you want to locate a match anywhere in string, use **search()** instead